# Spring Cloud Stream kafka-streams application shuts down on deserialization exception

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am using

spring boot: 2.3.5.RELEASE
spring cloud: Hoxton.SR8

I am trying spring cloud stream kafka-streams application. Everything was running fine till got a deserialization exception. Application shuts down everytime.

I want to skip bad records and move ahead in Kafka topic. But I am not able to achieve this.
Configuration:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: statsprocessor.${ENV}.${INSTANCE_ID}
  cloud:
    stream:
      instance-index: ${INSTANCE_INDEX}
      instance-count: ${INSTANCE_COUNT}
      bindings:
        statsInput:
          destination: ${STORE_INPUT_TOPIC}
          group: statsprocessor.${ENV}
          consumer:
            concurrency: ${CONCURRENCY}
            partitioned: true
            useNativeDecoding: true
      kafka:
        streams:
          bindings:
            statsInput:
              consumer:
                keySerde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
                valueSerde: per.shades.framework.kafka.serdes.CotsEventSerde
                startOffset: earliest
                applicationId: statsprocessor.${ENV}
                autoCommitOnError: false
                dlqName: ${STORE_INPUT_DLQ}
                useNativeDecoding: true
                configuration:
                  client.id: statsprocessor.${ENV}.${INSTANCE_ID}
          binder:
            auto-add-partitions: true
            auto-create-topics: true
            deserializationExceptionHandler: logAndContinue
            brokers:
              - ${KAFKA_URI}
            configuration:
              num.stream.threads: ${CONCURRENCY}
              buffered.records.per.partition: 500
              cache.max.bytes.buffering: 10485760
              commit.interval.ms: 500
              state.dir: ${KAFKA_STATE_DIR}
              replication.factor: ${DEFAULT_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR}
              reconnect.backoff.ms: 15000
              retry.backoff.ms: 10000
              producer.linger.ms: 100
              producer.acks: all
              producer.retries: 3
              producer.batch.size: 16384
              consumer.max.poll.records: 100
              consumer.session.timeout.ms: 60000
```

The error I get is

```
    Exception in thread "statsprocessor.local.1-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: 
Exception caught in process. taskId=0_4, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, topic=cots-event-store, partition=4, offset=0, stacktrace=org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException:
 ClassCastException invoking Processor. Do the Processor's input types match the deserialized types? Check the Serde setup and change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters. 
Make sure the Processor can accept the deserialized input of type key: unknown because key is null, and value: per.shades.model.events.CotsEvent.

Note that although incorrect Serdes are a common cause of error, the cast exception might have another cause (in user code, for example). For example, if a processor wires in a store, but casts the generics incorrectly, a class cast exception could be raised during processing, but the cause would not be wrong Serdes.
    ....
    ....
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class per.shades.model.events.CotsEvent cannot be cast to class per.shades.model.stats.StatsMetadata (per.shades.model.events.CotsEvent and per.shades.model.stats.StatsMetadata are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

Now I am using this setting `deserializationExceptionHandler: logAndContinue`.
Still it has no effect. As per documentation it should simply log error and continue processing. i.e it should skip bad record. But that doesnt happen. This error is seen.

`All stream threads have died. The instance will be in error state and should be closed.`

I also used

```
@Bean
public StreamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer streamsBuilderFactoryBeanCustomizer()
{
    return streamsBuilderFactoryBean ->
    {
        streamsBuilderFactoryBean.getStreamsConfiguration()                    .put(org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG,
                        ContinueOnErrorHandler.class);
    };
}
```

And handler class is

```
public class ContinueOnErrorHandler implements DeserializationExceptionHandler
{

    @Override
    public DeserializationHandlerResponse handle(ProcessorContext processorContext, ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> consumerRecord, Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>> We are here");
        return DeserializationHandlerResponse.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> map)
    {

    }
}
```

But this also is not working. It is not getting called.

I dont want to delete my Kafka topic to get rid of bad record. Really struggling to solve simple deserialization error. Please help !!

Edit: bindings code:

```
@Configuration
public interface StatsStreamBindings
{
    String statsInput = "statsInput";

    @Input(statsInput)
    KStream<String, StatsMetadata> statsInput();

}
```

processor signature

```
public void aggregateStats(KStream<String, StatsMetadata> inputStream)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class per.shades.model.events.CotsEvent cannot be cast to class per.shades.model.stats.StatsMetadata (per.shades.model.events.CotsEvent and per.shades.model.stats.StatsMetadata are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

You are not getting a `DeserializationException`, you are getting `ClassCastException invoking Processor`; this means the deserializer successfully deserialized to a `CotsEvent` but your processor expects a `StatsMetadata`.

`DeserializationExceptionHandler` only handles `DeserializationException`s.

Comment: Ok. I was having a doubt if that is so. However, if its not a deserialization error, how can I capture it? Because I have also added an uncaught exception error handler. But that is not getting called. Please see my edits, have added bindings code and processor signature as well. The error that I receive is something I cannot capture in my code. So please advise

Comment: It seems pretty clear. You have configured a ’CotsEventSerde’ but you are expecting a ’StatsMetadata’. You need to deserialize to the expected type.

Comment: Yes, I know that. However I dont want to change my deserializer. I want to make sure that wrong messages dont break my application. So if I send a wrong message type, application should just be able to skip the bad message. Currently application is stuck processing same bad messages everytime I start it. It is unable to skip those bad messages

Comment: Then the question is completely wrong. It has nothing to do with deserialization errors. I suggest you delete this and ask a new question that clearly explains what you want to achieve.

Comment: done, pls check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68037314/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-streams-application-uncaught-exception-handling

Comment: You are still talking about deserializationExceptionHandler there. As I have explained, that will only be invoked If the serde fails to deserialize. Don’t clutter the question with irrelevant info. You also need to show your stream topology since your question is really all about general error handling in a Kafka stream, which you have to add to the stream definition yourself.

Comment: Please comment in the new question. I am editing my question there