# Spring Cloud Stream kafka-streams application uncaught exception handling

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I am using

spring boot: 2.3.5.RELEASE spring cloud: Hoxton.SR8

I am using a custom serdes class like so

```
public class CotsEventSerde<T extends EventJsonSerializable> implements Serde<T>
```

where EventJsonSerializable is

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "_t")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CotsEvent.class, name = "cotsEvent"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ErrorDetails.class, name = "errorDetails"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = StatsMetadata.class, name = "statsMetadata"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = StatsMetadataKey.class, name = "statsMetadataKey"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = StatsKey.class, name = "statsKey"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Stats.class, name = "stats")
})
public interface EventJsonSerializable extends Serializable
{
}
```

So here I have created a common serdes class which can ser/deser multiple classes as mentioned in JsonSubTypes list above.

Now in one of my component running spring-cloud-stream kafka-streams binder, this is the binding class

```
@Configuration
public interface StatsStreamBindings
{
    String statsInput = "statsInput";

    @Input(statsInput)
    KStream<String, StatsMetadata> statsInput();

}
```

And processor signature is

```
public void aggregateStats(KStream<String, StatsMetadata> inputStream)
```

Now if I accidentally send a message of type CotsEvent or Stats then I get

```
Exception in thread "statsprocessor.local.1-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: 
Exception caught in process. taskId=0_4, processor=KSTREAM-SOURCE-0000000000, topic=cots-event-store, partition=4, offset=0, stacktrace=org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException:
ClassCastException invoking Processor. Do the Processor's input types match the deserialized types? Check the Serde setup and change the default Serdes in StreamConfig or provide correct Serdes via method parameters. 
Make sure the Processor can accept the deserialized input of type key: unknown because key is null, and value: per.shades.model.events.CotsEvent.

Note that although incorrect Serdes are a common cause of error, the cast exception might have another cause (in user code, for example). For example, if a processor wires in a store, but casts the generics incorrectly, a class cast exception could be raised during processing, but the cause would not be wrong Serdes.
    ....
    ....
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class per.shades.model.events.CotsEvent cannot be cast to class per.shades.model.stats.StatsMetadata (per.shades.model.events.CotsEvent and per.shades.model.stats.StatsMetadata are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

This means that deserialization has succeeded, but SCS (spring-cloud-stream) library couldn't convert CotsEvent to StatsMetadata as asked by processor signature/bindings.

But due to this error whole application breaks.

So my question is, how to handle such uncaught exceptions? I just want to skip such messages, probably send them to a DLQ and continue processing. But I am unable to find any such handler/hook in SCS library which can give me such a facility.

Maybe I can try using specific serdes instead of a generic serdes class. But can I still keep its flexibility and catch such errors instead?

Please help.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Spring, all it does is hook the binding to your KStream. You need to show your stream code. One solution would be to add a `.filter()` before your processor to ignore (and maybe log) unexpected inputs.

Comment: Your KStream would need `Object` as the value type. You can then add a `.map` to cast it to your concrete type.